# Spring Cloud Stream SSL connection with Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application using Spring Boot *2.0.3.RELEASE* and Spring Cloud Stream libraries under *Finchley.SR1*. With properties:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    ssl:
      protocol: SASL_SSL
      keystore-location: classpath:kafka.p12 // created from a PEM with private key and certificate
      keystore-password: passw0rd
      key-store-type: PKCS12
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
      ...
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      autoCreateTopics: false
                      brokers: myhost.mydomain.com
```

trying to establish an SSL connection with Kafka with properties:

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://myhost.mydomain.com:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://myhost.mydomain.com:9092
```

But I am getting following exception:

```
2018-08-29 17:49:13.421 ERROR [alef-data-connector,,,] 83300 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Cannot initialize Binder

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

2018-08-29 17:49:13.422 ERROR [alef-data-connector,,,] 83300 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder:
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:391) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:126) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:138) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:244) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:221) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:252) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:46) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:29) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:61) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.alefeducation.connector.ConnectorApplicationKt.main(ConnectorApplication.kt:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Is my configuration for my Spring Cloud Stream application correct. Do we have Spring Cloud Stream documentation explaining SSL connection with Kafka?

Comment: Not necessarily with SSL, but this sample application shows how to enable JAAS based security with kafka. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multibinder-samples/kafka-multibinder-jaas

Comment: I think the problem is he is using multi-binder configuration and hence the ssl stuff is not inherited.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell ... yes, have multi-binder configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use multi-binder support (via the `environment` property), there is no inheritance of root boot properties.

You either need to move the `spring.kafka.ssl` properties under the `environment` or, if you only have one binder, remove the multi-binder configuration and just declare the binder properties at the root.

**EDIT**

This works for me...

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: so52080276
          binder: kafka1
          group: so52080276
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      autoCreateTopics: false
                      brokers: myhost.mydomain.com
                      configuration:
                        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
                        ssl.keystore.location: classpath:kafka.p12 // created from a PEM with private key and certificate
                        ssl.keystore.password: passw0rd
                        ssl.key.store.type: PKCS12
```

Comment: When I configure `ssl.keystore.location`, `ssl.keystore.password`, `ssl.keystore.type`, `security.protocol=SASL_SSL` etc. under `binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration`, what am I mapping these property keys against and how do I know that they are correct property keys? With the guess work... lol, I've got `Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm`.

Comment: Kafka spits out the final consumer/producer/admin configuration at INFO log level on the console.

Comment: Doesn't get that far.

Comment: `ssl.truststore.location` and `ssl.truststore.password` worked for me instead of `ssl.keystore.location` and `ssl.keystore.password` respectively but maybe that is more to do with how `Kafka` is setup. But the `ssl.protocol` property key really needs to be `security.protocol`. Your guidance really helped getting it to work. Cheers.

Comment: The trust store is for server certificates that you trust; the key store contains a client certificate to be used if the server requires authentication of client certificates.

Comment: Ok, makes sense from what I was given, that I used to create my `truststore` (not `keystore`) :-). Thanks again.